# (x,y,z) coordinates for corona game development

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hi and good day stackoverflow community
how can i set an id for this kind of code using corona sdk/lua

the number 22 represents the current x position, for me to properly delete/destroy
some of the ground i need to pin point the coordinates of x,y,z
it should be like (1,1,1) or (2,1,69). Can please someone help me.
Thank you so much

```
    ground = {}
for i = 1, 68 do
    for j = 1, 100 do
        ground[i] = display.newImageRect( "assets/minebackground.png", 256 , 128)
        ground[i].x = -1500 + (i*50)
        ground[i].y =  5254 - (j*50) 
        physics.addBody( ground[i], "static" , { density=0.1, friction= 0 } )
           ground[i].id = i
    ground[i]:addEventListener("tap", oncollision)
 screenGroup:insert (ground[i])
  game : insert (ground[i])
    end
end
```

for pint pointing

```
function oncollision(event)
   ground = event.target
   return ground.id
end
```

Comment: First of all, an item can be a member of only one group at a time.  A group can go into a group, but 

screenGroup:insert (ground[i])
  game : insert (ground[i])

will result in ground[i] only being in the group "game".  

But to @vovahost's comment, I dont get what you mean by a Z coordinate.  Corona SDK is only a 2D engine.  But your event.target.x and event.target.y will have the X, Y of what was tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your onCollision function, event.target.x and event.target.y are the X and Y for the touched item.